# Adobe Flex Action Script - Response Object

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have the Adobe Flex Application, from the cgi script, i receive response Object as XML

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, httpResult);

loader.load(request);

private function httpResult(e:Event):void
{   
    Alert.show("XML: " + new XML(e.target.data));
    var result:XML = XML(e.target.data) as XML;
    Alert.show("hasOwnProperty(result): " + result.hasOwnProperty("result"));
}
```

Below is my Response Object at Alert "XML: "

```
<result>
    <update>insert</update>
</result>
```

But the Alert "hasOwnProperty(result): " shows "False"

Comment: I don't think you need to convert the data twice.  Try `var result:XML = XML(e.target.data)` or `var result:XML = e.target.data as XML;`  but not both.  My intuition is that you need the first one.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, the first one (`XML(e.target.data)`) **will** convert the `String` result into a `XML` (if it is properly formatted), the second approach will try to read the `String` as a `XML`, which **will fail**, as the `String` isn't a `XML` (it is a *XML formatted string*). 

By the way, the double casting isn't a problem, it's just redundant...

Comment: @NemoStein `e.target.data` is a generic Flex object; not a String. I know I've had conversion issues in some situations using `as Something` vs `Something()`.  I just never know, off the top of my head, which one was problematic.  Sounds like my intuition was right; that the first one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

`<result>` is the [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) of your XML.
Try the following:

```
private function httpResult(e:Event):void
{   
    var result:XML = XML(e.target.data);
    Alert.show("has update property: " + result.hasOwnProperty("update"));
}
```

---

**Edit**: To make it clear, take a look at the following code:

```
var xml:XML = XML("<result><update>insert</update></result>");

trace("XML:", xml);
trace("result:", xml.hasOwnProperty("result"));
trace("update:", xml.hasOwnProperty("update"));
```

The output in the console will be like this:

```
XML: <result>
  <update>insert</update>
</result>
result: false
update: true
```

Comment: -1.  I'm sorry; how is this any different than the code provided?  Did you do something other than remove the first alert and change the text string on the second alert?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, @Anton Sorry, I just forgot to change the value in the `result.hasOwnProperty()` call. I've edited and corrected the code.

Comment: I removed my downvote with your change.  I suspect you're on the right track.  I think the 'double conversion' in the original code may be problematic; but I'd need to step through code to make my mind sure.